# MySQL Trigger - Copy A Row From Active Table To Archive Table

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I'm having a problem creating a trigger on a database for a project

I've never used triggers before in MySQL and when i try to execute the below code it says there is an error at ' ' on line 4...

Here is the code

```
CREATE TRIGGER archiveCar AFTER UPDATE ON mms_cars
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
  IF NEW.active=2 THEN
   INSERT INTO mms_cars_sold SELECT * FROM mms_cars WHERE ad_id = OLD.ad_id;
   DELETE FROM mms_cars SELECT * FROM mms_cars WHERE ad_id = OLD.ad_id;
  END IF;
END;
```

I'm not sure if i'm creating this correctly so please excuse any amateur errors. My goal is to copy a the info for a row from an active table to an archive table when the status for the car has been set to 2 (i.e. Sold) in order to maximise search efficiency on the active table

Hopefully somebody can be kind enough to help me out

Kind regards

Barry

EDIT

I have now got the following

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER archiveCar AFTER UPDATE ON mms_cars
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
 IF NEW.active=2 THEN
  INSERT INTO mms_cars_sold SELECT * FROM mms_cars WHERE ad_id=OLD.ad_id;
  DELETE FROM mms_cars WHERE ad_id=OLD.ad_id;
 END IF;
END //
DELIMITER;
```

It produces this error:

## 1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: Try it without the delete statement, and see if the error is still ocurring

Comment: a) remove the `SELECT * FROM mms_cars` from your DELETE statement b) You might also be interested in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html (since you already have an integer field tht determines the status)

Comment: Will try those things,thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to drop the trigger before recreating new one.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER archiveCar;
CREATE TRIGGER archiveCar AFTER UPDATE ON mms_cars
...
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers
>   with the same action time and event for one table'

That means there's already an update trigger for mms_cars.